# Erro Python com PIP

Tags: python

Eu tentei instalar as dependências do meu projeto com o seguinte comando:

```
pip install -e $PROJETO/calculo-bonus
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> ERROR: /calculo-bonus is not a valid editable requirement. It should
> either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with svn+,
> git+, hg+, or bzr+).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira correta de fazer a instalação de dependências utilizando o pip é via um arquivo `.txt`.

Para gerar este arquivo é necessário rodar o comando:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Após executar este comando basta fazer a instalação das dependências no seu projeto, para isso basta executar o comando:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Caso já tenha instalado as dependências em uma execução do `env` anterior basta carregar o ambiente virtual novamente, utilizando o comando:

```
source env/bin/active
```

Saiba mais sobre arquivos de [`requisitos`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files), e os mais detalhes de funcionamento dos comandos mostrados acima.